# Работа с cookie файлами

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookie

Я делаю небольшой сайт в качестве проекта, и мне нужно реализовать на нем работу с куки файлами, но у меня нет никакой теоретической базы.

Вкратце, у меня есть сайт, который взаимодействует с БД, в которой хранятся данные о пользователях (имя и тд). Мне нужно, чтобы id пользователя в БД хранился в куки файлах пользователя, а при загрузке страницы он оттуда доставался. И если пользователь заходит впервые, создавать нового пользователя в БД и записывать его id в куки файлы пользователя.

Возможно ли такое реализовать, и насколько это сложно? Буду очень благодарен если объясните.

Comment: Такое возможно. В целом не сложно. Только вот логику немного надо переделать. В куку записывать ID  авторизированного пользователя, а не любого, у кого нет в куках ID. Иначе если почистить историю браузера, то старый клиент получит новый ID

Answer (score 0):

Есть масса роликов на YouTube и в самом интернете.

Вам нужно гуглить: "работа с cookies" и схожие запросы.

Вот один из роликов что нашел и вам подойдет для первого освоения:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWOzlN4zEgg